# How can I stop my swift app from crashing

Tags: ios, image, ipad, swift, memory

I am new to Swift programming and really have high hopes from all the experts out there. While creating a simple app I ran into memory issues and my app crashed. Below are more details about my app..

My app has an image view, three images and three buttons in toolbar. All my app does right now is changes image with button press. Example if you press say button1, it will load image1, if you press button2 it would load image 2 and if you press button 3 it would load image 3.

This app crash after 1 cycle, like I can tap all the three buttons and it would work, however if I tap on any button after that it would just crash.

I am testing this on iPad mini. Works perfectly fine on simulator. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I head somewhere that UIImage (named:) can be an issue, but I don't know how to replace that with anything else in Swift.

Here is the code for it

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
   @IBOutlet weak var TestImage: UIImageView!

   @IBAction func Button1(sender: AnyObject)
   {
      TestImage.image = UIImage (named: "Image1.jpg")

   }

   @IBAction func Button2(sender: AnyObject)
   {
      TestImage.image = UIImage (named: "Image2.jpg")
   }

   @IBAction func Button3(sender: AnyObject)
   {
      TestImage.image = UIImage (named: "Image1.jpg")
   }

   override func viewDidLoad()
   {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
}
```

Comment: can you post the crash log?

Comment: Crash log on iPad or one that is saved on MAC

Comment: the crash log that's seen in xcode debugger window.

Comment: Unrelated, but see [Cocoa naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE). Written for Objective-C, but is good guideline for Swift naming conventions, too.

Comment: Hi Hashmat thank you for your response :-) , there are no logs in Debugger Output Window. Any logs i get are under All output and that just shows me 2015-01-03 20:10:05.328  TCDS App[972:27690] Received memory warning.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `UIImage(named: name)` is that it caches the images. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) says:

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Thus, if you have memory problems arising from the size/number of images in the system cache, you can use `UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)` rather than `UIImage(named: name)`:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Image1", ofType: "jpg") {
    TestImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:path)
}
```

Comment: I tried it and now tapping on buttons will not change the image, do I need to save images on iPAD first or create directory ? As of now all three images are saved under Images.xcassets in Xcode and I am using this code for my swift program, do I need to switch to Objective C for using this code.. Thanks a ton Rob..

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the size using png 8 format in ps and it fixed the issue for me.. Thanks all for your help :-)