# Using contentsOfFile instead of image named

Tags: ios, swift

My app app crashes after showing Memory warnings on iPad Mini. After lots of research I found out that the problem is due to memory allocation using `UIImage( named:)` e.g:

```
SkipTutorial.image = UIImage(named: "skipTutorial.png")
```

And I should instead use `contentsOfFile` method so that the images are not cached. So I used:

```
if let imgPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("skipTutorial", ofType: "png") {
     SkipTutorial.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile:imgPath)
}
```

However this doesn't fetch the image. The images are in **Images.xcassets** in Xcode. Basically my app uses lots of images that don't need to be cached. I found a similar problem here:

[How can I stop my swift app from crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753772/how-can-i-stop-my-swift-app-from-crashing/27755452#27755452?newreg=d566308e1b5f4ecbab85d65cb201ad40)

and even his query is left unanswered in comments of how to use `contentsOfFile` method. I would really appreciate if someone helps me out here.

Comment: Add how `SkipTutorial` is defined.

Comment: @Zaph I didn't knew it would matter but here you go:
   
` var SkipTutorial = UIImageView()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `xcassets` as far as I know.

Simply include your images in a folder in Xcode, make sure they are copied to the bundle, and access them with

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(imageName, ofType: "png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
```

Comment: Just added the images to the xcode project folder. and ran the code as mentioned above. Thanks!